# In IOS App, I can't get the link entered in Associated Domains to open from Safari. It opens to home page

Tags: ios, xcode, appdelegate, ios-universal-links, associated-domains

I cannot get the correct url to open from Safari when it prompts me to go to the app. I have my app configured to the home page with WKWebView, and the universal link I set up in Associated Domains is the login page.

In the Associated Domains section of Xcode, I entered: applinks:mydomain.com/login-page. I've tried everything, but when I enter the sub domain in Safari, it always opens to: mydomain.com in the app. I have Associated Domains enabled in my Apple developer account. Here is the code for my apple-app-site-association file, which is in both the root directory and the .well-known directory:

```
 {
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
    {
      "appID": "TEAMID.com.-mydomain.MyDomain",
      "paths": ["login-page"]
    }
    ]
  }
}
```

Finally, this is the code I entered in the AppDelagate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                 continue userActivity: NSUserActivity,
                 restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool
{
    // Get URL components from the incoming user activity.
    guard userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb,
        let incomingURL = userActivity.webpageURL,
        let components = NSURLComponents(url: incomingURL, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true) else {
        return false
    }

    // Check for specific URL components that you need.
    guard let path = components.path,
    let params = components.queryItems else {
        return false
    }    
    print("path = \(path)")

    if let albumName = params.first(where: { $0.name == "albumname" } )?.value,
        let photoIndex = params.first(where: { $0.name == "index" })?.value {

        print("album = \(albumName)")
        print("photoIndex = \(photoIndex)")
        return true

    } else {
        print("Either album name or photo index missing")
        return false
    }
}
```

For some reason, the app is not reading the universal link that I set up. I have researched this high and low, and just can't find the solution. I know I'm leaving something out, but at this point, I don't know what it could be. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Mydomain.com/login-page is not a domain. It is a domain plus a path.  Remove the path. The site associate file determines which paths are delivered to your app. The plist file specifies the domains associated with your app. The app delegate method needs to have code to route the incoming url within your app.

Comment: I made the change you suggested, but no change.